# How can I write Junit Test case which takes URI as input?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am Trying to write test case for a method which takes URI as input and maps with modelmapper.

however, I am getting null pointer exception for this.

I have added every possible implementaion of class which I want to test.
if you guy's need more for compilation tell me in comment section.

this one is actual implementation which I want to mock

```
@Override
    public ApplicationScanConfigDTO getApplicationScanConfig(int account_id, String appAppScanConfigId) {

        URI getUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/").pathSegment("api/scheduleOnDemand")
                .queryParam("Account_Id", account_id).queryParam("applicationConfigScanId", appAppScanConfigId).build()
                .toUri();

        return modelMapper.map(apiClient.getOperation(getUri, Object.class), ApplicationScanConfigDTO.class);
    }
```

This is what I was trying

```
@Test
void testGetApplicationScanConfig() throws Exception {
    URI getUri = new URI("/api/scheduleOnDemand?Account_Id=1&applicationConfigScanId=1");

    modelmapper.map(restTemplate.getForEntity(getUri, JSONObject.class), ApplicationScanConfigDTO.class);
    

}
```

apiclient implementation

```
@Override
public <R> R getOperation(URI uri, Class<R> rClasss) {
    URI builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl)
            .path(uri.getPath())
            .query(uri.getQuery())
            .build()
            .toUri();
    
    return restTemplate.getForObject(builder, rClasss);
}
```

ApplicationConfigDTO actual implementation:

```
public class ApplicationScanConfigDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String serverName;

    private Integer accountId;

    private String ipAddress;

    private String subnetRange;

    private Integer credentialId;

    private String credentialName;

    private String os;

    private List<String> ibmLibrary;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }

    public void setServerName(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }

    public Integer getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Integer accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    public String getSubnetRange() {
        return subnetRange;
    }

    public void setSubnetRange(String subnetRange) {
        this.subnetRange = subnetRange;
    }

    public Integer getCredentialId() {
        return credentialId;
    }

    public void setCredentialId(Integer credentialId) {
        this.credentialId = credentialId;
    }

    public String getCredentialName() {
        return credentialName;
    }

    public void setCredentialName(String credentialName) {
        this.credentialName = credentialName;
    }

    public String getOs() {
        return os;
    }

    public void setOs(String os) {
        this.os = os;
    }

    public List<String> getIbmLibrary() {
        return ibmLibrary;
    }

    public void setIbmLibrary(List<String> ibmLibrary) {
        this.ibmLibrary = ibmLibrary;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying  to test  `modelmapper.map` or `getApplicationScanConfig`? If you  want to test `getApplicationScanConfig` the test needs to call it.

Comment: I want to test modelmapper.map but it is returning null

Comment: where modelmapper is initialized?

Comment: @X_R86 please edit your question to include the code that you're testing, and more of the test class (enough so that other people can compile it).

Comment: @TimMoore just have a look now